# Cargar Dashboards y estilos de grafana en el deplyment

Tags: docker

Llevo ya unas horas dando vueltas por internet y no veo la forma de hacer esto (y la docu de grafana para mi es poco intuitiva)
Os pongo en situación. Estoy desplegando grafana en Azure, pero después de desplegarlo, tengo que cargar los json con los Dashboards a mano y de uno en uno.
Estoy buscando la forma de hacer que a la hora de desplegar grafana, tambien se cargen automáticamente los dasboards... pero no veo nada de como hacerlo, y las cosas que veo son confusas o no son exactamente eso.
¿alguien que haya tenido este problema?
Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que esta web se explica bien el proceso:
https://www.adityakonarde.com/posts/provisioning-dashboards-grafana/